# Batch files - is not recognized as an internal command

Tags: batch-file

I created a. Batch that will run a model as follows. In Command Prompt (DOS) I do this: 
C:\Program Files\Portico\portico-1.0.2\exec> executePortico.bat name_model

Example: executePortico.bat ExampleCPPFederate

But this error:

'C: \ Documents' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, operable program or batch file.
"C:\Program Files\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\" ExampleCPPFe
derate.cpp
Press any key to continue. . .
'"C:\Program Files\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\" ExampleCPPF
ederate2 'is not recognized as an internal command
or external, operable program or batch file.
Terminated - Normal

See my code:

```
@echo off

rem ###########################
rem # implementation/version  #
rem ###########################


rem ################################
rem # check command line arguments #
rem ################################
:checkargs
if "%0" == "" goto usage
if "%1" == "" goto usage


rem #######################
rem # test for JAVA_HOME  #
rem #######################
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto nojava
goto rtihometest

:nojava
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!
goto usage

rem #######################
rem # test for RTI_HOME   #
rem #######################
:rtihometest
call C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsC.bat
if not "%RTI_HOME%" == "" goto execute


############################################
### (target) execute #######################
############################################
:execute
SHIFT
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR="C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\"
set EXEC="C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\"


if "%0" == "m" goto exec1

:exec1
echo %EXEC%%1%.cpp
pause
%EXEC%%1%.cpp %2
goto finish


:usage
echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end
```

---

I need to do the following:
I need to run the examples in this software so that way I created a file. Bat where in a Command Prompt I run thus:
executaPortic.bat name_model
i did this:

```
@echo off

rem ###########################
rem # implementation/version  #
rem ###########################


rem ################################
rem # check command line arguments #
rem ################################
:checkargs


if "%0"=="" goto usage
if "%1"=="" goto usage



rem #######################
rem # test for JAVA_HOME  #
rem #######################
if "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto nojava
goto rtihometest

:nojava
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!
goto usage

rem #######################
rem # test for RTI_HOME   #
rem #######################
:rtihometest
call C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsC.bat
if not "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto execute


############################################
### (target) execute #######################
############################################
:execute
SHIFT
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\
set EXEC=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\

rem ###########################
rem # if "%0"=="m" goto exec1
rem ###########################

goto exec1

:exec1
echo %EXEC%%1.exe
pause
"%EXEC%%1.exe" %2
goto finish


:usage
echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end
```

But now this error:
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\exec>executePortic.bat main
The input line is too long.

Comment: Take the spaces out from around your `==` in your `if` statements.  Also, remove the quotation marks from your `set RTI_FEDDIR=` and `set EXEC=` values and change `%EXEC%%1%.cpp %2` to `"%EXEC%%1%.cpp" %2`.

Comment: Before that changed the installation location to C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2
I did what you said, please see the part of the code: 

`:execute
SHIFT
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13
set EXEC=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\


if "%0"=="m" goto exec1

:exec1
echo %EXEC%%1%.cpp
pause
"%EXEC%%1%.cpp" %2
goto finish


:usage
echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end`

</br></br>

Comment: but this error occurs:  
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\exec>executePortico.bat main  
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\.exe  
Press any key to continue. . .  
'"C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\2' is not recognized as an internal command or external, operable program or batch file. 
Terminated - Normal

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a couple of other minor syntax errors, such as replacing `%1%` with `%1` and adding quotation marks to your `call blah\blah\confvarsC.bat` line.  There are a couple of other potential problems that I can't fix without knowing what the script expects as arguments or seeing example usage.  I marked those with `!!!!!!` comments.

```
@echo off

rem ###########################
rem # implementation/version  #
rem ###########################


rem ################################
rem # check command line arguments #
rem ################################
:checkargs
if #%1==# goto usage
if #%2==# goto usage


rem #######################
rem # test for JAVA_HOME  #
rem #######################
if "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto nojava
goto rtihometest

:nojava
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!
goto usage

rem #######################
rem # test for RTI_HOME   #
rem #######################
:rtihometest
call "C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsC.bat"
if not "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto execute


rem ############################################
rem ### (target) execute #######################
rem ############################################
:execute

rem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
rem !!!!  SHIFT is useful if you have more than   !!!!
rem !!!!  9 arguments.  Otherwise, there's no     !!!!
rem !!!!  reason to use it.  After this, I can't  !!!!
rem !!!!  tell whether you expect %2 to be the    !!!!
rem !!!!  second script argument or the third.    !!!!
rem !!!!  -- rojo                                 !!!!
rem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

SHIFT
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\
set EXEC=C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\


if "%0"=="m" goto exec1

rem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
rem !!!!  Shouldn't there be some sort of    !!!!!
rem !!!!  "else goto" statement here?  As    !!!!!
rem !!!!  the script runs now, it will goto  !!!!!
rem !!!!  exec1 regardless of whether        !!!!!
rem !!!!  "%0"=="m"  -- rojo                 !!!!!
rem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


:exec1
echo %EXEC%%1.cpp
pause
"%EXEC%%1.cpp" %2
goto finish


:usage
echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end
```

Comment: See what I did:

1 - At the command prompt:   
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\exec>executePortico.bat main  
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\main.exe  
Press any key to continue. . .  
ERROR [main] portico.lrc: Fed file doesn't exist: file=file:/C:/Portico/portico-1.0.2/exec/testfom.fed
org.portico.lrc.compat.JCouldNotOpenFED: Fed file doesn't exist: file=file:/C:/Portico/portico-1.0.2/exec/testfom.fed  
  
If I put the file executePortico.bat in the C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13, so this way works.